# How to disable all apache virtual hosts?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I'm writing a shell script to do some web server configuration. I need to disable all currently active virtual hosts. `a2dissite` doesn't accept multiple arguments, so I can't do

```
a2dissite `ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`
```

Should I use `find`? Is it safe to manually delete the symlinks in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is your script Debian only? If so, you can safely delete all the symlinks in sites-enabled, that will work as long as all sites have been written correctly, in the sites-available directory.

For example:

```
 find /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ -type l -exec rm -i "{}" \;
```

will protect you against someone who has actually written a file instead of a symlink in that directory.

(remove the -i from rm for an automatic script, of course)

Comment: **EDIT of my previous comment - Updated for Debian Stretch:**
Based on your answer, I would recommend go with `find /etc/apache2/sites-available/ -type f -exec basename '{}' \; | xargs -n 1 a2dissite` so you stay safe if the a2dissite script changes in the future...

Answer (score 25):

You can just do the following:

```
sudo a2dissite '*'
```

or:

```
sudo a2dissite
```

and it will prompt you for the ones you want to disable.

When you have finished disabling sites, restart apache2 server:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

or just reload apache configuration without a full restart:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: That only works if you are in `/etc/apache/sites-enabled` (or similar directory).

Comment: @StephanVierkant: `*` will cause shell to do globbing and match all files in the current directory, which, as you noted, might work only if you are in `/etc/apache/sites-enabled` directory. To pass `*` literally as a parameter (which `a2dissite` does support as wildcard), use `'*'` instead.

Answer (score 13):

After a little more research, I found out that `a2dissite` is just a shell script, and it basically just calls `rm`. So, like other responses, I agree that it is safe to do

```
rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*
```

Answer (score 6):

To remove the host file just delete it.
If you just want to **dissable** the site, use

```
sudo a2dissite sitename
```

Restart apache2

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Again to remove (delete)it completely from the system,

```
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-available/sitename
```

I would also disable it first before deleting the file

Answer (score 2):

You can just delete the symlinks, or move the entire directory away. There is no special database or other metadata besides those links.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. All `a2ensite` or `a2dissite` does is create or delete links in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory. Moving the directory away might be a bit excessive for most people, though.

Answer (score 1):

I never use 'a2dissite ' and always delete and create the links in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled manually so yes, I'd say it's pretty safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workaround, first type:

`# a2dissite` (type this command without any argument, it would prompt to ask you choose the next line)

> Your choices are: **siteA siteB siteC siteD**
>
> Which site(s) do you want to disable (wildcards ok)?

Now you just copy all of above list of sites (**siteA siteB siteC siteD**) and paste into as your answer, then Enter.

The output result would be:

```
removing dangling symlink /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/siteA.conf
removing dangling symlink /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/siteB.conf
removing dangling symlink /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/siteC.conf
removing dangling symlink /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/siteD.conf
```

This approach will help us to optional to choose to a long list of names of site should be removed or intact.

Answer (score -1):

you can edit the httpd.conf and delete the include line for the virtual hosts (at the bottom of the file)

Comment: well, this is being done by a shell script, and there's no assurance what the structure of the httpd.conf file is

Comment: he can use regex. include is preety much the same. he could pass the dir of the vhosts as an argument and based on that he can build the regex

Comment: neither is there an assurance that all vhosts are defined in config files linked from the sites-enabled dir.

Comment: That'd interfere with the ability to quickly activate some of those vhosts in the future, though.

Answer (score -3):

Apparently, you can just install the latest Ubuntu  ;)